# Is it possible to handle NO_DATA_FOUND exception inside trigger in PL SQL?

Tags: oracle, plsql, triggers

I am trying to create a trigger to randomly generate a group_id in my table, if it is NULL after insertion. Here is something I've tried to do:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER add_group
BEFORE INSERT ON students FOR EACH ROW
DECLARE
    group_var NUMBER(6) :=0;
BEGIN
    SELECT group_id 
    INTO group_var
    FROM students
    WHERE student_id = :NEW.student_id;
    EXCEPTION
    WHEN NO_DATA_FOUND THEN
        group_var:=0;
    IF group_var IS NULL THEN
        UPDATE students
        SET group_id = ROUND(DBMS_RANDOM.VALUE(1,6));
    END IF;
END;
```

Comment: Please [edit] your question with a [MRE] including: the DDL (`CREATE TABLE`) statement or your table; and an (English, not code) description of the problem your trigger is trying to solve (possibly including a simple example of your expected result from an insert) as it is not clear from your description what you expect to happen.

Comment: Sorry, but your code has too many elementary mistakes. I just hope you are a student, not an actual professional in the field. You are selecting from `students` where the student id matches the one you are inserting? Shouldn't id's be unique? if you are inserting, the id shouldn't exist in the table already. Also, towards the end, you have an `update` statement that, if it executed, it would update **all rows** in the `students` table, giving every row a new, random group id. Etc. It seems you have more basic misunderstandings than just how a trigger should function.

Comment: You are right, I am a student. Thank you for pointing to my mistakes. I will try to be more careful.

Answer (score 2):

> I am trying to create a trigger to randomly generate a group_id in my table, if it is NULL after insertion.

It appears that if an inserted row has a `NULL` value for `group_id` then you want to generate a random integer between 1 and 6 and assign that to the `group_id`.

```sql
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER add_group
BEFORE INSERT ON students
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
  IF :NEW.group_id IS NULL THEN
    :NEW.group_id := FLOOR(DBMS_RANDOM.VALUE(1,7));
  END IF;
END;
/
```

*(Note: do not use `ROUND(DBMS_RANDOM.VALUE(1,6))` as the values 1 and 6 have half the probability of being generated as the intervening values do.)*

Then, for the table:

```sql
CREATE TABLE students (
  student_id INT
             GENERATED ALWAYS AS IDENTITY
             PRIMARY KEY,
  group_id   INT
             NOT NULL
             CHECK ( group_id BETWEEN 1 AND 6 )
);
```

If you do:

```sql
INSERT INTO students ( student_id, group_id ) VALUES ( DEFAULT, NULL );
INSERT INTO students ( student_id, group_id ) VALUES ( DEFAULT, 4 );
```

Then the table may contain:

> ```
> STUDENT_ID | GROUP_ID
> ---------: | -------:
>          1 |        5    <-- This was randomly generated
>          2 |        4    <-- This was the non-random value from the INSERT.
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=f3876a2457031fdc33b872cbeedf9340)*

Comment: Thank you for the quick and clear answer!